# Valor do Select

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Eu tenho um `select` com várias marcas de carros e tenho um *script* que quando selecionar o carro deve aparecer as suas marcas. Eu queria atualizar as marcas, mas quando carrego no botão para atualizar só a última marca e o modelo escolhido é que atualiza.

Código HTML

```
<select name='marca'  placeholder='marca' id='marca'onChange='onSelectChange()' '$row->marca' required/>
    <option value ='$row->marca'>$row->marca  - marca do seu veiculo </option></br>
    <option value='Alfa Romeo'>Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option value='Aston Martin'> Aston Martin</option>
    <option value='Audi'>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Código dos modelos

```
<select size='1' name='modelo' id='modelo0' style='display:none;'>
    <option selected value='modelo'>modelo</option>
    <option value='100'>100</option>
    <option value='80'>80</option>
    <option value='A1'>A1</option>
    <option value='A3'>A3</option>
    <option value='A4'>A4</option>
    <option value='A5'>A5</option>
    <option value='A6'>A6</option>
    <option value='A7'>A7</option>
    <option value='A8'>A8</option>
    <option value='Q2'>Q2</option>
    <option value='Q3'>Q3</option>
    <option value='Q5'>Q5</option>
    <option value='Q7'>Q7</option>
    <option value='R8'>R8</option>
    <option value='TT'>TT</option>
</select>

<select size='1' name='modelo' id='modelo1' style='display:none;'>
    <option selected value='modelo'>modelo</option>
    <option value='asdas'>aasas</option>
    <option value='dasdas'>asdasd</option>
</select>

<select size='1' name='modelo' id='modelo2' style='display:none;'>
    <option selected value='modelo'>modelo</option>
    <option value='dasdasdsa'>sadsadsad</option>
    <option value='asdcccascasas'>aaasdasdsas</option>
    <option value='dasadasdsdas'>dsadasd</option>
</select>
```

Código JavaScript

```
function onSelectChange() {
    var value = document.getElementById("marca").value;

    if ( (value == 'Audi')) {
        document.getElementById('modelo0').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('modelo0').style.display = 'none';
    } 

    if ( (value == 'Alfa Romeo')) {
        document.getElementById('modelo1').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('modelo1').style.display = 'none';
    } 

    if ( (value == 'Aston Martin')) {
        document.getElementById('modelo2').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('modelo2').style.display = 'none';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Debuga se está entrando em cada if.

Comment: O que seria este "carrego no botão para atualizar"?

Answer (score 1):

Alterei um pouco o script, acredito que dessa forma funcione do jeito que você espera, ao invés de utilizar a estrutura `if else`, utilizei o `switch case`, pois é mais eficiente:

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $('#marca').change(function(){
          var marca = $('#marca').val();    
          switch(marca){ 
  case '':
   $('#modelo0, #modelo1, #modelo2').hide();
   break;
  case 'Audi':
   $('#modelo0').show();
   $('#modelo1, #modelo2').hide();
   break;
  case 'Alfa Romeo':
   $('#modelo1').show();
   $('#modelo0, #modelo2').hide();
   break; 
  case 'Aston Martin':
   $('#modelo2').show();
   $('#modelo0, #modelo1').hide();
   break;
  default:
   $('#modelo0, #modelo1', '#modelo2').hide();
                        break;
        }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name='marca'  placeholder='marca' id='marca' required/>
 <option value=''>Selecione a marca do seu veiculo </option></br>
 <option value='Alfa Romeo'>Alfa Romeo</option>
 <option value='Aston Martin'> Aston Martin</option>
 <option value='Audi'>Audi</option>
</select>

<select size='1' name='modelo' id='modelo0' style='display:none;'>
    <option selected value='modelo'>modelo</option>
    <option value='100'>100</option>
    <option value='80'>80</option>
    <option value='A1'>A1</option>
    <option value='A3'>A3</option>
    <option value='A4'>A4</option>
    <option value='A5'>A5</option>
    <option value='A6'>A6</option>
    <option value='A7'>A7</option>
    <option value='A8'>A8</option>
    <option value='Q2'>Q2</option>
    <option value='Q3'>Q3</option>
    <option value='Q5'>Q5</option>
    <option value='Q7'>Q7</option>
    <option value='R8'>R8</option>
    <option value='TT'>TT</option>
</select>

<select size='1' name='modelo' id='modelo1' style='display:none;'>
        <option selected value='modelo'>modelo</option>
        <option value='asdas'>aasas</option>
        <option value='dasdas'>asdasd</option>


</select>

<select size='1' name='modelo' id='modelo2' style='display:none;'>
        <option selected value='modelo'>modelo</option>
        <option value='dasdasdsa'>sadsadsad</option>
        <option value='asdcccascasas'>aaasdasdsas</option>
        <option value='dasadasdsdas'>dsadasd</option>
</select>
```